# Scanning File with String and int Java

Tags: java, split, delimiter, scanning

So i have a .dat file that is a list. Each line starts with a letter as a command for my alarm clock program and some are followed by numbers in time format (XX:XX). I need to scan the letter arr[0] so the program knows which method to implement and then separate the integers from the colon to have arr[1] and arr[2]. I can't seem to figure out how to do both.

Example :T 25:00

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()){
  String[] data = scan.nextLine().split(" ");

   if (data[0] == "D"){
    myClock.getTime();
  }
  else if (data[0] == "A"){
    myClock.getAlarmTime();
  }
  else if (data[0] == "T"){
    myClock.setTime(data[1], data[2]);
  }
  else if (data[0] == "S"){
    myClock.setAlarmTime(data[1], data[2]);
  }
  else if (data[0] == "O"){
    myClock.setAlarmOn(true);
  }
  else if (data[0] == "F"){
    myClock.setAlarmOn(false);
  }
  else{
    myClock.quit();
```

tells me I have incompatible types and that .String cannot be converted to int. So how do I convert or scan the two separately?

Comment: I wouldn't use scanner. I wouldn't separate the integers. Read the file using [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) and then parse each line to a [`enum Command`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and a [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). Java is an OO language - learn to use that to your advantage rather than fight against it. Continued...

Comment: sorry edited it to include the rest of my code

Comment: ...have `Command implements ClockCommand` which is an `interface` with a method `apply(LocalTime time)`. Then when you have parsed the `enum` with `Enum.valueOf` you just need to call `command.apply(time)`. No `if..else` chains. Just clean, descriptive OO logic.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
String str[] = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
```

place

```
String str[] = scan.nextLine().split(" |:");
...............
if (str[0].equals("T"))
myClock.setTime(Integer.parseInt(str[1], Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
```

One more issue is `if (data[0] == "T" )` means compaing strings

In java, we should use `equals()` for checking strings equality whether both are same or not.

Instead of

```
 if (data[0] == "T" )
```

use

```
if (data[0].equals( "T" ))
```

Comment: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Comment: yea i just figured that out. much appreciated tho

Answer (score 0):

If your error is at this line `myClock.setAlarmTime(data[1], data[2]);`, try to convert it to int.

Mby your functions for `setAlarmTime` and `setTime` need ints and you are passing Strings, compiler normally advise this.

Try this:

```
myClock.setAlarmTime(Integer.valueOf(data[1]), Integer.valueOf(data[2]));
```

Also, you want to separate this `T 25:00`to this: { "T","25", "00" }

And with this line `String[] data = scan.nextLine().split(" ");` you will get:  { "T","25:00" }

You need to split again your data[1] before do `setAlarmTime` and `setTime` with:

```
String[] timeSplit = data[1].split(":");
myClock.setAlarmTime(Integer.valueOf(timeSplit[0]), Integer.valueOf(timeSplit[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

loosely based on @Boris the Spider comment

```
public class EnumCommand {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("csv.dat"));
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
            MyCommand.valueOf(st.nextToken()).execute(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

private enum MyCommand {
    D {

        @Override
        public void execute(String predicate) {
            //getTime

        }
    },
    A {
        @Override
        public void execute(String predicate) {
            //getAlarm Time

        }
    },
    T {
        @Override
        public void execute(String predicate) {
            //setTime .. Parse here for time
            System.out.println(predicate);

        }
    },
    S {
        @Override
        public void execute(String predicate) {
            //set alarm Time Parse here for time
            System.out.println(predicate);

        }
    },
    O {
        @Override
        public void execute(String predicate) {
            //On alarm

        }
    },
    F {
        @Override
        public void execute(String predicate) {
            //Off alarm

        }
    };

    public abstract void execute(String predicate);
}
}
```